# Updating the status bar style between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

In my `info.plist`, file I have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES`

I have a `FirstViewController` where the status bar is hidden.

In my `SecondViewController` I have

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

However, the status bar is showing up, but is black.

How can I get it to update correctly? Thanks

Edit:

`AppDelegate.swift` also has this

`UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a great deal of misunderstanding promulgated about how to govern the status bar style when your view controller is a child of a navigation controller.

Your child view controllers can implement `preferredStatusBarStyle`, and this will work correctly if the navigation bar is *hidden*.

If the navigation bar is *showing*, the navigation controller sets the status bar style based on the navigation bar's `barStyle` — to `.default` if the bar style is `.default`, and to `.lightContent` if the bar style is `.black`. So the correct way for your view controller to set the status bar style, when the navigation bar is showing, is to set the navigation controller's navigation bar style.

The obvious place to do this is in `viewWillAppear`, which is called whenever this view controller becomes the top of the navigation controller's stack:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black // or .default
}
```

Comment: Since this is such a source of misunderstanding, some code examples would be helpful for me and future people who come across this. From the research I've done, no one has written a good answer to this question, hence my confusion

Comment: but when you override  the status bar style in your controller's viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear method , by adding UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default // or .light the status bar changes fine

Comment: @MhmdRizk It may seem to work, but I'm showing what Apple intends you to do. It's very poorly / not documented, but I got this technique from an Apple employee on the Apple developer forums. The navigation controller responds automatically by setting the status bar style in accordance with the navigation bar's bar style. This leaves each view controller in charge of the status bar style, which is the modern architecture. So it's better to do that than to go "over the head" of the navigation controller by talking directly to the application.

Comment: i have one more question, do we need to add this 
View controller-based status bar appearance property in Info.plist file 
thanks in advance.@matt

Comment: @MhmdRizk No. That's totally outdated. View controller control of the status bar has been the default for many years.

Comment: Has something changed/broken since this was a working solution?  I can successfully change the navigation bar style on the fly (to .black and back to .default at will), but I am utterly unable to convince the status bar to change its display to show light text on a black navigation bar.  I've tried all the solutions I've been able to find here on SO, all to no avail.  Any suggestions on what else I might be missing?

Answer (score 23):

There is a property in `Info.plist` file called **View controller-based status bar appearance**. It should be set to **YES**.
Then in your UIViewController you should override `preferredStatusBarStyle`:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Here is one important thing to notice: if you have view controllers embedded into UINavigationController and your view controller's `preferredStatusBarStyle` method not getting called - you will have to workaround it by writing something like following:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}
```

What it does is simply asking top controller for it's statusbar style, and update appropriately

Comment: Thanks Valerii. That extension was the answer I've been looking for here all morning

Comment: @ZackShapiro The correct way to govern the status bar style from within a view controller that is the child of a navigation controller is to set the navigation controller's navigation bar's `barStyle`.

Comment: @matt Show me? Submit an answer?

Comment: Thanks, extension did the work done in navigation controller. no need to add any thing in `plist` and no need to add navigation `barStyle`

Comment: Where does this go in my code?  Do I need to explicitly call this somehow?  I have VCs embedded in navigation controllers, in both parts of a split view controller, and while I can change the navbar style from .default to .black and back at will on the fly, I am utterly unable to convince the status bar to change its display to light text on the .black navbar.  Any suggestions on what I might be missing?

Comment: after you change status bar style, you should call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621354-setneedsstatusbarappearanceupdat

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5, iOS 12**

Most of the answers here were helpful, but didn't immediately solve the issue for me. I have a nested structure (root VC > tab bar VC > navigation VC > specific page VC) and I wanted one of the pushed page VCs to change the status bar color.

Setting `navigationBar.barStyle` in the page VC did nothing for me, perhaps because the navigation VC wasn't a top level VC. Setting `preferredStatusBarStyle` did not work in the page VC either (though it did work if I overrode this property in the root VC).

@kelin's answer set me on the right direction however. `childForStatusBarStyle` helps specify which child VC should be examined for the proper style. Here were the steps I took:

**Step 1**: Implement `childForStatusBarHidden` for all VCs in my VC hierarchy.

e.g. for the root VC

```
override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
  // this is a custom var I've set up
  return currentViewController
}
```

for the tab VC

```
override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
  return selectedViewController
}
```

for the nav VC

```
override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
  return topViewController
}
```

**Step 2**: Make sure that `childForStatusBarStyle` is called correctly. My root VC's `currentViewController` variable was not getting set before iOS checked, so I needed to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` after that variable was set to indicate that `childForStatusBarStyle` needed to be checked again.

**Step 3**: In the child VC that is determining the status bar appearance, override the style:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
  return .lightContent
}
```

**Step 4**: Make sure to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` when the child VC is created, and call it from the root controller. So, `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in the child VC didn't work, but e.g. `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` did.

**Step 5**: When the child VC is removed from the hierarchy and you want to revert the status bar style back, be sure to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` from the root VC again, perhaps in `viewWillDisappear`.

As a side note, the above solution did not require me to explicitly set the `View controller-based status bar appearance` Info.plist value to `YES` that many answers reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative solution for UINavigationController. You can subclass it and use `childForStatusBarHidden` property in couple with `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`.

```
class StatusBarNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }

    override var viewControllers: [UIViewController] {
        didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() }
    }
}
```

So the status bar style will be defined by the `topViewController`.