# Status bar color won't change no matter what

Tags: ios

I'm trying to change the status bar color for one specific screen in my application.
The background in that screen is dark so I'm trying to use the white status bar instead.
I tried using:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Which did worked at first, But I added a `TabBarController` to my application and there I added 4 `navigation controllers` (one for each item), this is how it looks:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let homeController = HomeVC()
    let homeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
    homeNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    let favoritesController = WishlistVC()
    let favoritesNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: favoritesController)
    favoritesNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true


    let cartController = CartVC()
    let cartNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cartController)
    cartNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true

    let storeController = BaseStoreVC()
    let storeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: storeController)
    storeNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true


    homeController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: home_string, image: UIImage(named: "home"), tag: 0)
    favoritesController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: favorites_string, image: UIImage(named: "favorites"), tag: 1)
    cartController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: cart_string, image: UIImage(named: "cart"), tag: 2)
    storeController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: store_string, image: UIImage(named: "store"), tag: 3)

    let tabBarItems = [homeNavigationController, favoritesNavigationController, cartNavigationController, storeNavigationController]

    viewControllers = tabBarItems

    setupTabBarAppearance()
}
```

Since then, the status bar color on the screen stays black.
The screen I'm trying to change belongs to the `homeNavigationController` (not the `homeController` though).
I move from the `homeController` to the screen I'm trying to change like this:

```
    let vc = ProductDetailVC()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I tried using this in the ProductDetailVC() too:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Which also didn't work.

Comment: You can look this same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838772/8956604)

Comment: Thanks, I looked at @matt answer, this is exactly what I have now, and the navigation bar is also hidden but still it won't change.

Answer (score 1):

The right to govern the status bar style belongs to the top view controller. Since you changed your architecture, that is now the tab bar controller. It relegates the decision to its current child, which is a navigation controller. Only the tab bar controller or its current child has any say in the matter. So it is the home navigation controller’s `preferredStatusBarStyle` that counts. The product detail VC is not consulted. That explains why your attempt to use `preferredStatusBarStyle` fails.

However, that was never going to work *anyway*, because, as you already know, the way a navigation controller decides its status bar coloring is based on the nav bar's bar style. In the architecture you describe, it worked for me to have the product VC set the bar style:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: So if I do want the status bar to be white just on one screen on the homeNavigationController, but to be black on the rest, is this not possible?

Comment: Added possible solution.