# iOS 13 Status bar style invalid (childForStatusBarStyle never called)

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, statusbar, uistatusbar

I've been searching a lot, but didn't find the same problem as my on **StackOverflow** or anywhere else.

---

### Setup

- `Info.plist`

  - `ViewControllerBasedStatusBar` set to `YES`
  - `StatusBarStyle` set to `.lightContent`
  - `UserInterfaceStyle` set to `.light` (app doesn't support `.dark` mode)
- Each `UIViewController` has its own implementation of `preferredStatusBarStyle`:

  ```
  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return .lightContent
  }
  ```
- `UITabBarController` has `extension`:

  ```
  open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
      return selectedViewController
  }
  ```
- `UINavigationController` has `extension`:

  ```
  override open var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
      return topViewController
  }
  ```

---

### Problem

<strike>Since iOS 13 released my status bar logic was broken and I can't understand why. On iOS <= 12.4 everything works properly. `childForStatusBarStyle` is never called and each viewController has some random style</strike>.

**UPDATE**: Since iOS 13 released status has style based on `UserInterfaceStyle` set global, not based on `preferredStatusBarStyle`(with proper setup) in case of `UITabBarController` -> `UINavigationController` -> `UIViewController` hierarchy.

---

### Question

The question is how to solve this problem? Did something silently changed in this logic? (Checked many articles and changelogs)

---

### Reproduction

I've been able to reproduce the bug in the sample project with everything set up as mentioned above.

[Here](https://github.com/Erumaru/ios-status-bar-bug) I have github project which contains view hierarchy as follows:

```
CustomTabBarController
 - UINavigationController
   - CustomViewController
 - CustomViewController
```

Now, when you select the first tab app has dark style status bar, when the second selected light style one. CustomViewController has `preferredStatusBarStyle` set to `.lightContent`.

**More**:

- **Xcode**: Version 11.5 (11E608c)
- **Device**: iPhone 8 Simulator
- **iOS**: Version 13.5

---

**P.S:** I'm ready and will provide more details on the topic, don't hesitate to ask me to do so. Project is running more than 2 years and thing like this is really to debug :)

Comment: Please make [mcve] and post it.

Comment: @matt okay, I’ll try to create sample project

Comment: Thanks, that will be a big help.

Comment: Yes, looks like a bug, let's submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: @matt I've just added the sample project with the described problem. Can you please check it out?

Comment: @Asperi Looks a bit strange. Can you please check the sample project?

Comment: @Erumaru Thanks for the github project. Can you explain now what the issue is supposed to be? What is happening, and what did you wish to happen instead? To me the app in your project looks well behaved.

Comment: Hi, I face the same problem, could you quote your solution if you ever found one... Thanks !

Comment: @DenisPinna Hi, I've used my solution provided below. matt's solution is more clear and also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a navigation controller situation, the status bar style (light/dark) does not depend, and has never depended, on anything except the navigation bar style. Add this line in your project's custom tab bar:

```
    let bugVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
    bugVC.navigationBar.barStyle = .black // *
```

Now the status bar text is white in both of the tab bar controller's children. (And if you then don't like the color of the navigation bar, which is the default black, you can change it; that won't affect the behavior of the status bar.)

Comment: If you look at extensions I've implemented for both(`UITabBarController` and `UINavigationController`) method `childForStatusBarStyle` and in the first tab there have to be `preferredStatusBarStyle` of `ViewController`.

Comment: No need to be hostile. If you look at my answer it tells you how to make the status bar be light in a navigation controller situation. I stand by that. What I'm telling you has always been the right way. See for instance my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47837959/updating-the-status-bar-style-between-view-controllers/47838772#47838772

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There is nothing about hostile, really appreciate your help! I gonna check it out.

Comment: I've just downgraded the sample project to `iOS 12.4` deployment target and it's working as I expected (Always been working). Please, try to run it on `12.4` simulator. Print in `childForStatusBarStyle` is called and `UINavigationController`'s status bar style set to be what returned in `preferredStatusBarStyle` of `ViewController` class.

Comment: Then, try to run again on `13+` iOS and print won't be called. So this is the question I've asked: "The question is how to solve this problem? Did something silently changed in this logic? (Checked many articles and changelogs)"

Comment: Of course yes, it changed, But what you were doing was always wrong. I'm trying to tell what was always the _right_ way.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying such a tricky moment, does there exist any source that states about deprecating the wrong use of `childForStatusBarStyle` in `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 4):

For those to whom using `.barStyle` is a big deal in case of time, there is a workaround. Subclass `UINavigationController`, then call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` each time `viewControllers` change.

---

### Sample code

```
class WorkaroundNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
    
    override var viewControllers: [UIViewController] {
        didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For `UINavigationController` - `UIViewController` structure, add code below to navigation controller. Then override child view controller's `preferredStatusBarStyle`, it worked for me.

```swift
override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
    visibleViewController
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    visibleViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
}
```